# Simplifying integral $\int_3^4 \sqrt{(x - 3)(4 - x)} dx$

Tags: integration

So I have this Integral $$\int_3^4 \sqrt{(x - 3)(4 - x)} dx$$

I know by the property, I can replace $x$ with $7-x$, then I am getting the same integral, how can I approach the problem considering this step?

Or it's not possible to move further from the step above.

options for this problem are

$(a) π/4 (b) π/8 (c) π/2 (d) none$

Moreover, can you suggest to me some way to approach this problem?

Comment: Can I take advantage of the property I mentioned?

Comment: @Ankit Yes, that means the function is symmetrical across $x = 7/2$ which motivates the substitution $x = t + 7/2$.

Comment: additionally, substitution and then IBP works well too

Comment: And can I always find this x=7/2 from x=(a+b)/2, a and b begin upper and lower limits?

Comment: Hint: $\int _{a}^{b}\sqrt{( x-a)( b-x)} \ =\ \frac{\pi }{8}( b-a)^{2} \ \ ( b >a)$

Answer (score 1):

The integrand is $\sqrt{-(x-3(x-4)}=\sqrt{-((x-4)+1)(x-4)}$ so when you substitute $x=4-\sin^2t$, you have $\frac{dx}{dt}=-2\sin t\cos t$ and $$\sqrt{-((x-4)+1)(x-4)}=\sqrt{-\cos^2t(-\sin^2t)}=\cos t\sin t$$. You can take it from there.